# opencart 2 модуль liqpay. как формируется запрос?

Tags: opencart

Как и из чего формируется post запрос в модуле Liqpay?

Comment: Нашёл. https://www.liqpay.com/ru/doc - всё подробно расписано, и запрос, и ответ.